# Powerapps form custom dropdown

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am trying to make a form in powerapps that has a custom dropdown as a selection.
I have 2 lists that are connected to powerapps, Courses and Departments.

I am trying to make a form that adds an entry to Courses but I cant get it to add data from a dropdown list that is reading from the Departments list.
If I do `DropDown1.SelectedText.Value` it shows the value I have selected. Does anyone have any ideas?

Edit:

Code of submit button:

```
SubmitForm(AddCourseForm);
NewForm(AddCourseForm);
Refresh(AXT_Bookings)
```

Code of drop down box:

```
SortByColumns(Distinct(Sections, Title), "Result")
```

Here are pictures of my code. The drop down is under a data card.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm not too late, but have you tried the patch function?

I can't explain why the submit doesn't work, but try this:

```
Patch(list,item(perhaps with lookup),{Column: Dropdown.SelectedText});
```

BR
Marcel

Comment: It turns out I had deleted the on update so it was not pulling the data from the drop down. Thanks for helping